# Link Generation - Routing - Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am learning Zend Framework 2 as it seems to be quite interesting. Unfortunately I can't find a good book to teach my self the framework.

I am interested in knowing which class/object is used to generate links. Lets take some examples:

1. Module M has controllers C and actions A1 and A2, assume I am in the view of A1 and am needing to put a link to the controller A2?
2. Module M has controllers C1 and C2. From the C1A action of C1, how can I generate a link to C2's C2A action?
3. Got 2 modules, Module M1 and Module M2. Both modules have controllers M1C and M2C respectively and each having index actions. From the index controller of M1C (first module), how can I make a link to M2C (of the second module) ?

I am following the Zend Skeleton Application. I wanted to create a link from Application module - Layout view to another view in another module. Well it is a menu item link.

I think the above 3 scenarios will cover most of such links.

I think routing should play a role in this. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

As Sam said, what you are looking for is the [Url view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#url-helper). If you look in the Zend Skeleton Application's configuration file, you will see that there is a [convenient route for this](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L27-L51).

To generate a URL to a given action within the Application module, you should be able to do like this:

```
echo $this->url('application/default', array(
    'controller' => 'MyController',
    'action' => 'MyAction',
));
```

This route is for the Application module, but you could create a similar route for any other module and then still do as above. The first parameter is the name of the route. You can [reference child routes with the URL view helper](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/zf2-view-helper-and-child-routes); before the slash is the parent route and after the slash is the name of the child route. I guess you could also create a generic route which also takes the module name as a parameter (segment).

As for finding a book, I bought [this book](https://leanpub.com/zendframework2-en) by Michael Romer. I never finished it, but what I read of it was good, although there were quite a few grammar mistakes, but I presume that those are fixed by now. Either way, that book would be a safe bet I'd say.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to work yourself through the [UserGuide](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#userguide).

You want also to take a closer look at the [`Zend\View\Helper\Url`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#url-helper)

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest you the "Using Zend Framework 2" book available here:
http://leanpub.com/using-zend-framework-2
Use this coupon for 90% discount: DI$COUNT